# "502: Bad gateway" error after 2 hours of https get requests

Tags: python, json, api, bots

I created a .py file that through GET requests gets data from taapi.io through their api key and so on. The main goal of this project (my first one) is to analyze some indicators of a crypto pair. I can send 30 request/api, so I set my script to wait 0.6 seconds before handling another request.
Till here all ok, I get my data in json file every 0.6 seconds. The problem happens after usually 45min/1h, and I get this error in the console:

```
File "C:\Users\andry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from 
None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\andry\Desktop\trad bot\PRova\import requests - 
v.1.0.5.py", line 139, in <module>
    result = response.json()    
  File "C:\Users\andry\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 917, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>api.taapi.io | 502: Bad gateway</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />        
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" /><meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
<script type="text/javascript"> 
(function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify){var e=function(a){var c=document.getElementById("error-feedback-survey"),d=document.getElementById("error-feedback-success"),b=new XMLHttpRequest;a={event:"feedback clicked",properties:{errorCode:502,helpful:a,version:1}};b.open("POST","https://sparrow.cloudflare.com/api/v1/event");b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");b.setRequestHeader("Sparrow-Source-Key","c771f0e4b54944bebf4261d44bd79a1e");
b.send(JSON.stringify(a));c.classList.add("feedback-hidden");d.classList.remove("feedback-hidden")};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var 
a=document.getElementById("error-feedback"),c=document.getElementById("feedback-button-yes"),d=document.getElementById("feedback-button-no");"classList"in a&&(a.classList.remove("feedback-hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!0)}),d.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!1)}))})}})();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="p-0">
        <header class="mx-auto pt-10 lg:pt-6 lg:px-8 w-240 lg:w-full mb-8">
            <h1 class="inline-block sm:block sm:mb-2 font-light 
text-60 lg:text-4xl text-black-dark leading-tight mr-2">        
              <span class="cf-error-type">Error</span>
              <span class="cf-error-code">502</span>
            </h1>
            <span class="inline-block sm:block font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">Ray ID: 6f868c98089d5a3d &bull;</span>
            <span class="inline-block sm:block font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">2022-04-07 23:30:07 UTC</span>  
            <h2 class="text-gray-600 leading-1.3 text-3xl font-light">Bad gateway</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="my-8 bg-gradient-gray">
            <div class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto">
                <div class="clearfix md:px-8">
<div id="cf-browser-status" class=" relative w-1/3 md:w-full py-15 md:p-0 md:py-8 md:text-left md:border-solid md:border-0 md:border-b md:border-gray-400 overflow-hidden float-left md:float-none text-center">
  <div class="relative mb-10 md:m-0">
    <span class="cf-icon-browser block md:hidden h-20 bg-center 
bg-no-repeat"></span>
    <span class="cf-icon-ok w-12 h-12 absolute left-1/2 md:left-auto md:right-0 md:top-0 -ml-6 -bottom-4"></span>
  </div>
  <span class="md:block w-full truncate">You</span>
  <h3 class="md:inline-block mt-3 md:mt-0 text-2xl text-gray-600 font-light leading-1.3">Browser</h3>
  <span class="leading-1.3 text-2xl text-green-success">Working</span>
</div>
<div id="cf-cloudflare-status" class=" relative w-1/3 md:w-full 
py-15 md:p-0 md:py-8 md:text-left md:border-solid md:border-0 md:border-b md:border-gray-400 overflow-hidden float-left md:float-none text-center">
  <div class="relative mb-10 md:m-0">
    <span class="cf-icon-cloud block md:hidden h-20 bg-center bg-no-repeat"></span>
    <span class="cf-icon-ok w-12 h-12 absolute left-1/2 md:left-auto md:right-0 md:top-0 -ml-6 -bottom-4"></span>
  </div>
  <span class="md:block w-full truncate">Milan</span>
  <h3 class="md:inline-block mt-3 md:mt-0 text-2xl text-gray-600 font-light leading-1.3">Cloudflare</h3>
  <span class="leading-1.3 text-2xl text-green-success">Working</span>
</div>
<div id="cf-host-status" class="cf-error-source relative w-1/3 md:w-full py-15 md:p-0 md:py-8 md:text-left md:border-solid md:border-0 md:border-b md:border-gray-400 overflow-hidden float-left md:float-none text-center">    
  <div class="relative mb-10 md:m-0">
    <span class="cf-icon-server 
block md:hidden h-20 bg-center bg-no-repeat"></span>
    <span class="cf-icon-error w-12 h-12 absolute left-1/2 md:left-auto md:right-0 md:top-0 -ml-6 -bottom-4"></span>
  </div>
  <span class="md:block w-full truncate">api.taapi.io</span>    
  <h3 class="md:inline-block mt-3 md:mt-0 text-2xl text-gray-600 font-light leading-1.3">Host</h3>
  <span class="leading-1.3 text-2xl text-red-error">Error</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">      
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="w-1/2 md:w-full float-left pr-6 md:pb-10 md:pr-0 leading-relaxed">  
                    <h2 class="text-3xl font-normal leading-1.3 
mb-4">What happened?</h2>       
                    <p>The web server reported a bad gateway error.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="w-1/2 md:w-full float-left leading-relaxed">
                    <h2 class="text-3xl font-normal leading-1.3 
mb-4">What can I do?</h2>       
                    <p class="mb-6">Please try again in a few minutes.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feedback-hidden py-8 text-center" id="error-feedback">
    <div id="error-feedback-survey" class="footer-line-wrapper">        Was this page helpful?  
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-yes" type="button">Yes</button>        
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-success feedback-hidden" id="error-feedback-success">
        Thank you for your feedback!
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
  <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item 
sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">6f868c98089d5a3d</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>   
    <span class="cf-footer-item 
sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Your IP</span>: 79.30.26.115</span>     
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>   
    <span class="cf-footer-item 
sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a 
rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
  </p>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->   
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
: 0
```

Did I make a mistake? What can I do to avoid this problem? (I also sent an email to the taapi service but I’m sure it’s not their fault.)

Comment: It looks like your code tried to parse an HTML document as JSON. It contains a description of the problem.

Comment: Ok I’ll try to understand what you mean exactly. Still don’t get why it runs for a couple of hours and then suddenly randomly it stops.

Comment: It could be a problem on the server side. Never write your program as if everything you get will be clean data without any problems. In this case you might want to log the errror and continue with the task. It might work the next time you call it.